# How to use GetRawInputData from C#?

Tags: c#, user32

I'm trying to acquire keyboard input using GetRawInputData and C#. I don't seem to be able to actually read the RAWINPUTDATA fields, no matter what I use for the definition of the call.

I have tried this:

In response to the WM_INPUT message, I try this...

```
void ProcessRawInput(Message message)
{
    uint dwSize = 0;
    uint retval;

    User32.RAWINPUT rawInput;

    retval = User32.GetRawInputData(message.LParam, User32.RAWINPUT.RID_HEADER, out rawInput, ref dwSize, Marshal.SizeOf<User32.RAWINPUTHEADER>());

    if (rawInput.header.dwType == (int)User32.RIM_TYPE.RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
    {

    }
}
```

It seems to read some data into the header structure, but nothing in the RAWINPUTDATA structure.

I tried something like:

```
    if (rawInput.header.dwType == (int)User32.RIM_TYPE.RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
    {
        // set dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf<User32.RAWINPUT>()
        retval = User32.GetRawInputData(message.LParam, User32.RAWINPUT.RID_INPUT, out rawInput, ref dwSize, Marshal.SizeOf<User32.RAWINPUTHEADER>()); 
    }
```

But the only difference seems to be a *huge* value returned as retval.

I cannot seem to find a useable example (in C#).

My definitions and structures look like this:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern uint GetRawInputData(IntPtr hRawInput, uint uiCommand, out RAWINPUT pData, ref uint pcbSize, int cbSizeHeader);

     [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RAWINPUT
    {
        public const int RID_INPUT = 0x10000003,
                         RID_HEADER = 0x10000005;
        public RAWINPUTHEADER header;
        public RAWINPUTDATA data;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RAWINPUTHEADER
    {
        public int dwType;
        public int dwSize;
        public IntPtr hDevice;
        public IntPtr wParam;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct RAWINPUTDATA
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public RAWMOUSE Mouse;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public RAWKEYBOARD Keyboard;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public RAWHID HID;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RAWKEYBOARD
    {
        public ushort MakeCode;
        public ushort Flags;
        public ushort Reserved;
        public ushort VKey;
        public uint Message;
        public ulong ExtraInformation;
    }
```

Comment: Check out my source code: https://github.com/VollRahm/NotEnoughHotkeys/blob/develop/src/NotEnoughHotkeys/NotEnoughHotkeys/RawInputLib/RawInput.cs#L39

Comment: Many thanks. I looks at your code and, by looking at the other source files in that locn, I could find my error. Credit to you, VollRahm.

Comment: No problem :D always here to help

Comment: Just one thing... do you know why "rawInput.data.Keyboard.VKey" always seems to be upper-case ? (ie. I hit the "a" and I get 65)

Comment: Those are NOT Letter codes, those are Virtual-KeyCodes. 65 is 0x41 in Hex, which is the A key on the keyboard. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes. C# has a method to convert the VkeyCode to an C# key

Comment: So... if I understand correctly, the raw input just tells me that the "A" key has been pressed - not whether it is shifted (ie. upper or lower case). I modified my code to display the hex value and I can see that the shift (0x10) and the caps-lock (0x14) have no effect on the 0x41. I tried calling User32.MapVirtualKey, but that didn't help. Do I need to maintain state for the keyboard (so that I can work out the uppercase/lowercase of the keyboard before the key press ?

Comment: Raw Input doesnt tell you if any modifier Key like shift was pressed. You need to log those yourself.